# If not exist for insert or update on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I want to insert a row , if the row does not exists and if it exists, I want to update the row. I am currently using PLSql Oracle.
When I want to write a query like this;

```
IF NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID=1)
   INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(ID,NAME)VALUES(1,'CAGDAS SANCARBARLAZ')
ELSE
   UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NAME='UGUR CAN' WHERE ID=1
```

How can I do that in Oracle Sql  ?

Comment: can we use the column names we want for the merge ?

Comment: Why are you using a different value for the `name` in the UPDATE and the INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) for that.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_NAME T
   USING (SELECT 1 ID from dual) S
   ON (T.ID = S.ID)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.NAME='UGUR CAN'
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'CAGDAS SANCARBARLAZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement. Providing the constant values is a bit messy, because Oracle does not support the standard VALUES constructor, so you need to use a `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` for the source of the MERGE statement:

```
merge into table_name
using (
  select 1 as id, 'CAGDAS SANCARBARLAZ' as name from dual
) t on t.id = table_name.id
when matched then update
   set name = 'UGUR CAN'
when not matched then insert (id, name) values (t.id, t.name);
```